# How to fetch the tags for ec2-describe-instances in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to extract the instance ID and the tags from the result of a command ec2-describe-instances and want to store the result in a text file. The result set gives :

But i want the tags owner and cost.centre also to be fetched
Kindly guide me how to do that

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: the ec2-describe-instances gives a no of attributes, i just want the instance id and the tags like name, cost centre and owner to be fetched from the result.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
ec2-describe-instances |awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/(name|owner|cost.center)/&&/tag/'

TAG instance    i-c4    Name    Rii_Win_SAML
TAG instance    i-c42   Owner   Rii Pandey
```

Comment: I want the tags related to a single instance in a single line.

Comment: can you update your sample file, the current one makes me confused on how to get the result. for example, I didn't see `Naveen` in source file, but you ask to it in output.

Comment: actually the file is too long i have fetched only a part

Comment: hey you are quite close to what i want. but now I am getting the out put i have posted in question. I want to print tags for a single instances in a single line

Comment: please help me out im stuck :(

Comment: I read your question for three times after you updated, but I still don't get the meaning. You have to space time to explain your question to let others know what you need. you need provide at least two instances, and provide the output which get from these instances.

Comment: you are quiet close I want the owner tag to be in the same line as the name tag is

Comment: how in the same line? something like this :`TAG     instance        i-c4260db8      Name    Risi_Win_SAML Owner   Ri Pey`

Comment: `ec2-describe-instances |awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/(name|owner|cost.center)/&&/tag/'` command is able to this, But there is one problem

Comment: i want the order to be NAme, cost centre, owner despite of the order that the user has defined

Comment: can you please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

this will help to find instance-id

$ aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-xxx |   awk '{ print $8 }' | sort -n   | grep  "i-"

i-4115d38c

i-5d534697

i-6e679a45

i-7a659851

i-8d6bae40

i-cd6f9000

i-d264ad1e

i-d5888618

i-e2332e2e

ps considering that you already configured / run "aws configure"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you just need to add expressions to your 2nd grep:

```
ec2-describe-instances | grep -i "tag" | grep -i -e "name" -e "owner" -e "cost.centre"
```

Comment: see the updated question I want the reult to come in a single line for a single instances !!!

Comment: can you please help me Digital trauma

Comment: @user3086014 As you may have guessed, I have no familiarity with `ec2-describe-instances`.  I am coming from this purely from a bash/shell perspective.  So the output of `ec2-describe-instances` is pretty much meaningless to me.  For instance you want name and owner on the same line.  Name and owner for a given instance ID?  Is "i-c4" an instance ID?  What about cost.center?  I have no idea which field in the output corresponds with that.

Comment: You are much more likely to get quality answers to your question if you improve the quality of the question - in particular include all relevant information in a consistent and unambiguous way.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer's [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22651675/2113226) is probably the better one.  Make sure you pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: yeah i hav installed that tool and have converted the output to json format and i dont know how to fetch the details

Comment: if u can help please help me out. i know nothing about json and all that stuff

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be unnecessarily complicated to do in a shell script. Here are some suggestion:

1. you are using `ec2cli`. Don't use that. Use `AWS-CLI` instead. Because parsing the output in `ec2cli` is a pain. Whereas `AWS-CLI` provides output in `JSON`, it is way more easier to parse. Also, AWS is going to support `AWS-CLI` only henceforth.
2. The information that you need a perfect use-case for using a hash. You can either install and run `AWs-CLI` commands via a perl script and then capture the output in a hash. `Perl` is very powerful for handling such data structure.
3. OR, you can use one of the SDKs from AWS (I use Ruby SDK) and then capture the whole information in a hash and then print it the way you want.

Bottom line is, you need to capture the tags in a hash to make your life easier. Ans this becomes more and more prominent when you have multiple tags.

Comment: read the documentation: http://aws.amazon.com/cli/. Take some good time and read it carefully. You are going to thank me later. I just cannot live without it ever since I started using it.

Comment: but it would take time. could you help me with this only aws cli tools ?

Comment: I had burned my fingers parsing the ec2cli output a 1000 times. I hope someone else might be able to help you with that.

Comment: if you can please help me out

Comment: can you modify BMW's answer ?

Comment: I give up and i have installed the aws-cli tool. nowi will let you know where i stuck

Comment: but aws-cli tools also give output in the json format

Comment: Hey!! i have configured aws cli tools using python now what should be my next step?

Comment: @user3086014 Remember people answer who questions here get no compensation, other then imaginary internet points.  A barrage of demanding comments is not likely to encourage folks to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do without using jq and other parsing tools.

```
ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0],Tags[?Key==`cost.centre`].Value | [0]]' --output text
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "owner"},{Key: "costcenter"}]}))|"Instance ID: \(.InstanceId) Owner: \(.Tags[]|select(.Key=="owner")|.Value), Cost Center: \(.Tags[]|select(.Key=="costcenter")|.Value)"'
```

TL;DR: The way AWS does tags is a living nightmare, even with `jq`

Also, use AWS CLI, not old, unsupported tools.