# How to get the data in a single line in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using the `Amazon Cli tools` to write an `ec2 audit script`.I want to fetch the `tags like name, owner, cost centre` from the `ec2-describe-instances`.

I am using this command :

```
ec2-describe-instances | grep -i "tag" | grep -i -e "name" -e "owner" -e "cost.centre"
```

please help

Comment: it is giving data in a paragraph not formatted way

Comment: Update your question to show whats your expected output?

Comment: yeah see or i want to to have headinga like instance id, name, owner etx then there are value

Comment: why did you deletd the post

Comment: Post the content of your file without the `grep` so that we know how to format it to your expected output. With current sample data it is difficult to get to a solution.

Comment: I want heading on top and values on bottom

Comment: see the output of ec2-describe-instances updated in my question

Comment: Please help, im stuck from last 10 days

Comment: You first ask the output to come in single line and now you are asking for headings at top and values on bottom. I'm confused as to what you want as output. Clearly specify your requirement in your question. Post sample data that covers different scenarios. Are some tags missing Names or Owners?

Comment: sorry question edited

Comment: yes some tags like owner etc are missing for some instances

Comment: Unfortunately not easily with `awk`. There are different number of spaces between your tags so will end up breaking at on or the other point.

Comment: then what should i do ???

Comment: this command  `ec2-describe-instances | grep -i "tag" | grep -i -e "name" -e "owner" -e "cost.centre"` gives output for a single instance in multiple lines based on no of tags. and by using your answer it is giving me the output but not in expected way. Its quiet unformatted

Comment: can you help me out ????

Comment: okay is it possible that we write the output in file with name, owner, tag in it ?

Comment: Can we write the output taken in a single line for an instance and write it to a file !!!

Comment: @jaypal : Can you please post again the command that you posted as an answer ??? WE can modify it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch the tags for ec2-describe-instances in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650661/how-to-fetch-the-tags-for-ec2-describe-instances-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe your existing command to `awk` for formatting ...

```
ec2-describe-instances | grep -i "tag" | grep -i -e "name" -e "owner" -e "cost.centre" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]=a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]?a[$1FS$2FS$3] FS $4 FS $5:$4 FS $5}END{for(x in a) print x, a[x]}'
```

Comment: @user3086014 Make sure that you have copied the command exactly like I have given above.

Comment: yes i have copied the command exactly and should i write all this in a shell script?

Comment: @user3086014 Looks like you are running into an issue pasting multi-line command. I modified the answer to be all in one line. Try it out and see if that helps. No you dont need a shell script. You can run this on command line.

Comment: i have tried now there is another issue for some instances owner tag is oming first and for other name is coming first. Is this possible that we can use name, owner, instance id, cost centre as heading and below the, values and if a tag is blank is should be left blank or fill with NULL.

Comment: i have another command `ec2-describe-instances |awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/(name|owner|cost.center)/&&/tag/'` Can we write the values for i single instance in one line ?

Comment: please help me if you can. i am fed up and frustrated because of this. Please help me out. I will be very thankful to u

Comment: hey do you know how to parse json output in linux?

Comment: please have  a look at my question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678461/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-with-linux