# How to do this in linux

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, awk, amazon-ec2

I am writing a script. I am using the amazon-cli tools to fetch the data from the console.

My requirement is to write few attributes of the instances in a file in a specific order.

Like Instance-id , name, owner, cost-centre in a row for a single instance.

I am struggling on this a lot.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the 4th time your are asking the same question in a span of 3 hours.

Comment: @user3086014: What is your desired output?

Comment: Your input has `i-c42` but output has `i-efcf`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch the tags for ec2-describe-instances in a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650661/how-to-fetch-the-tags-for-ec2-describe-instances-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
ec2-describe-instances | awk '/([nN]ame|[oO]wner|cost\.centre)/&&/TAG/{
   $3 = tolower($3);
   $4 = tolower($4);
   if (!($3 in c)) { 
      c[$3];
      b[++i]=$3;
   }
   a[$3,$4]=$5 " " $6;
}
END {
   print "Instance id", "Name", "Owner", "Cost.centre";
   for(k=1; k<=i; k++)
      print b[k], a[b[k],"name"], a[b[k],"owner"], a[b[k],"cost.centre"]
}' OFS='\t' | column -ts$'\t'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Instance id  Name                      Owner       Cost.centre
i-c42        Rii_Win_SAML              Rii Pandey  1243
i-55         RDS_Machine (us-east-1c)  Joseph
```

Comment: and it is only printing the name not owner cost centre etc

Comment: Can there be more than 1 unique tag in output OR only one unique tag?

Comment: tag value means `i-efcf`

Comment: So in same output there can be multiple `Name` line and multiple `Owner` lines?

Comment: I cannot keep fixing it without real input data. After so many iterations do you believe you have provided real input data produce the output shown in your question.

Comment: Still missing details. Your output has `i-8a6` but inout doesn't have `i-8a6`. Don't put data in comments

Comment: my answer already has that but have to say that your question is of pretty poor quality and on top of that you aren't providing me correct input data.

Comment: Output from `ec2-describe-instances` which produces output as you expect in your question.

Comment: ok I give up. I tried to be as helpful as possible and spent hours on this. Ask a friend of yours to make you understand what I wrote in comments above.

Comment: I have tried my best but unfortunately you're not understanding my comments and I cannot understand your problem without input data. With above input data my awk command works fine.

Comment: I left a comment on your other question.

Comment: can u help me in this if i  provide u with the required data ?

Comment: Yes that is what I have been saying for long time.

Comment: Now i think so i have provided the reuired details and please give it a last shot sir

Comment: Probably you'e still not getting it. Your desired output is `i-c4b8` but inout doesn't have it. I cannot really guess your input data.

Comment: Anubhava sir i dont know why it is giving me only one instance repeatedly

Comment: Sir, i would like to emphasize on the fact that ec2-describe instances gives 100 of instance details but due to space limitation i have provided detail of only 1 instance. Now i have provided you with the correct input and output but the code that you have provided is not working. Can u help ?

Comment: Do we need to handle case sensitivity ?? may be that is an issue

Comment: I have updated the sample output from ec2-describe instances may be that will help us rectifying error and i have also updated the question

Comment: I am bit busy now, will check it in the evening.

Comment: sorry to respond late. See updated code in answer now.

Comment: @fedorqui: lol :) Thanks and I almost gave up few times but OP just didn't let it go.